# Error when posting image with Facebook PHP SDK v4

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

Since I'm on PHP 5.4, I am using this code to post image to Facebook:

```
$response = (new FacebookRequest(
          new FacebookSession($session, 'POST', '/me/photos', array(
            'url' => 'https://url/to/my/pic.jpg',
            'message' => 'Message here'
          )
        ))->execute()->getGraphObject();
```

However this returns the following exception from the Facebook SDK:

```
Exception occurred Code 100 Unsupported POST request
```

What is driving me nuts is that the same API call works great when used with a Test Version App I created. Just not with the real app. Any hints? P.S. I'm using the Test Accounts Facebook provides.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a syntax issue to me, parentheses to be specific. You're passing the POST information to the `FacebookSession` constructor. Try this:

```
$session = new FacebookSession('ACCESS_TOKEN');
$response = (new FacebookRequest($session, 'POST', '/me/photos', array(
        'url' => 'https://url/to/my/pic.jpg',
        'message' => 'Message here'
      )))->execute()->getGraphObject();
```

Answer (score 0):

your passing a bad parameter, it
   array(
            'source' => new \CURLFile('https://url/to/my/pic.jpg'),
            'message' => 'Message here'
          )